# how to create an array of one class using a different classes objects? Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create an array of Fleet that contains Boat objects. I am currently getting an error that these cannot be converted to eachother.

```
public class Fleet {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Fleet[] boats = new Boat[args.length];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your boat class extends Fleet class?

Comment: ..And if it doesn't, make it extend the `Fleet` class(if you want to use it that way).

Comment: @R.J: No, that would be like making Animal extend Zoo, or Zoo extend Animal. Neither class should extend the other

Comment: I suppose if you had a 100-boat fleet, and 99 of them sank, you might refer to the remaining boat as "what's left of the fleet", in which case you could argue that it is now a single-boat fleet...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Logically, what you said is right, but is the OP insists on using `Fleet[] boats = new Boat[args.length];`, then Boat needs to extend Fleet. That is what I meant.

Comment: @R.J: It is highly likely that the OP is wrong in this situation and his code is wrong.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Yeah, that's true. But I've seen many OPs in the recent days insisting on what helping them solve their code as such, without much amendments. Nevertheless, as I said, you're right about a Fleet having an array of boats and not the otherwise.

Comment: It is not at all uncommon in math, and therefore in software, to stretch the usage of words that are borrowed from natural language. In graph theory, a single tree (or no tree at all) constitutes a forest. It seems equally reasonable to define "fleet" as "0 or more boats" for the purpose of some computation.

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to do this. Fleet should contain an array of Boat, not an array of Fleet.

i.e.,

```
public class Fleet {
  private Boat[] boats;

  public Fleet(int size){
    boats = new Boat[size];
    for (Boat boat : boats) {
      boat = new Boat();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int boatCount = 10;
    Fleet fleet = new Fleet(boatCount);
  }
}
```

Otherwise it's like saying a Fleet is a collection of Fleet which it's not.

Also, your main method should likely not contain this array, but rather the Fleet object should.

Note that neither class should extend the other, or it would be like saying Zoo extends Animal or Animal extends Zoo. A Zoo contains Animals, and a Fleet contains Boats (Ships actually).

Comment: And now it makes all sense with the full explanation. +1! :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work only if `Boat` extends from `Fleet`

Else you can go ahead with,

```
  Fleet[] boats = new Fleet[args.length];
```